# Allennlp 2.10.1 Predictor throws "Not implemented" and "KeyError" Errors

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, allennlp

I'm trying to use Allennlp's Predictor for Correference Resolution. It works fine in Google Colab, but altough the dependencies are identical it throws an error when I tried the same code in my local. Here is the full error log and my code:

```
from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor

model_url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/allennlp-public-models/coref-spanbert-large-2020.02.27.tar.gz'
predictor = Predictor.from_path("../coref-spanbert-large-2020.02.27.tar.gz")
```

The errors below don't give too much detail about the problem. I even tried to download the model and to give its path. It didn't work also. I think Predictor object is the problem here.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:653, in TraitType.get(self, obj, cls)
    652 try:
--> 653     value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
    654 except KeyError:
    655     # Check for a dynamic initializer.

KeyError: 'layout'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # model_url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/allennlp-public-models/coref-spanbert-large-2020.02.27.tar.gz'
----> 2 predictor = Predictor.from_path("../coref-spanbert-large-2020.02.27.tar.gz")

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/predictors/predictor.py:366, in Predictor.from_path(cls, archive_path, predictor_name, cuda_device, dataset_reader_to_load, frozen, import_plugins, overrides, **kwargs)
    363 if import_plugins:
    364     plugins.import_plugins()
    365 return Predictor.from_archive(
--> 366     load_archive(archive_path, cuda_device=cuda_device, overrides=overrides),
    367     predictor_name,
    368     dataset_reader_to_load=dataset_reader_to_load,
    369     frozen=frozen,
    370     extra_args=kwargs,
    371 )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/models/archival.py:232, in load_archive(archive_file, cuda_device, overrides, weights_file)
    229 config = Params.from_file(os.path.join(serialization_dir, CONFIG_NAME), overrides)
    231 # Instantiate model and dataset readers. Use a duplicate of the config, as it will get consumed.
--> 232 dataset_reader, validation_dataset_reader = _load_dataset_readers(
    233     config.duplicate(), serialization_dir
    234 )
    235 model = _load_model(config.duplicate(), weights_path, serialization_dir, cuda_device)
    237 # Load meta.

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/models/archival.py:268, in _load_dataset_readers(config, serialization_dir)
    262 # Try to use the validation dataset reader if there is one - otherwise fall back
    263 # to the default dataset_reader used for both training and validation.
    264 validation_dataset_reader_params = config.get(
    265     "validation_dataset_reader", dataset_reader_params.duplicate()
    266 )
--> 268 dataset_reader = DatasetReader.from_params(
    269     dataset_reader_params, serialization_dir=serialization_dir
    270 )
    271 validation_dataset_reader = DatasetReader.from_params(
    272     validation_dataset_reader_params, serialization_dir=serialization_dir
    273 )
    275 return dataset_reader, validation_dataset_reader

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/common/from_params.py:604, in FromParams.from_params(cls, params, constructor_to_call, constructor_to_inspect, **extras)
    602     # mypy can't follow the typing redirection that we do, so we explicitly cast here.
    603     retyped_subclass = cast(Type[T], subclass)
--> 604     return retyped_subclass.from_params(
    605         params=params,
    606         constructor_to_call=constructor_to_call,
    607         constructor_to_inspect=constructor_to_inspect,
    608         **extras,
    609     )
    610 else:
    611     # In some rare cases, we get a registered subclass that does _not_ have a
    612     # from_params method (this happens with Activations, for instance, where we
   (...)
    615     # you've done the right thing in passing your parameters, and nothing else needs to
    616     # be recursively constructed.
    617     return subclass(**params)  # type: ignore

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/common/from_params.py:636, in FromParams.from_params(cls, params, constructor_to_call, constructor_to_inspect, **extras)
    633 else:
    634     # This class has a constructor, so create kwargs for it.
    635     constructor_to_inspect = cast(Callable[..., T], constructor_to_inspect)
--> 636     kwargs = create_kwargs(constructor_to_inspect, cls, params, **extras)
    638 return constructor_to_call(**kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/common/from_params.py:206, in create_kwargs(constructor, cls, params, **extras)
    203 annotation = remove_optional(param.annotation)
    205 explicitly_set = param_name in params
--> 206 constructed_arg = pop_and_construct_arg(
    207     cls.__name__, param_name, annotation, param.default, params, **extras
    208 )
    210 # If the param wasn't explicitly set in `params` and we just ended up constructing
    211 # the default value for the parameter, we can just omit it.
    212 # Leaving it in can cause issues with **kwargs in some corner cases, where you might end up
    213 # with multiple values for a single parameter (e.g., the default value gives you lazy=False
    214 # for a dataset reader inside **kwargs, but a particular dataset reader actually hard-codes
    215 # lazy=True - the superclass sees both lazy=True and lazy=False in its constructor).
    216 if explicitly_set or constructed_arg is not param.default:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/common/from_params.py:314, in pop_and_construct_arg(class_name, argument_name, annotation, default, params, **extras)
    311 if popped_params is None:
    312     return None
--> 314 return construct_arg(class_name, name, popped_params, annotation, default, **extras)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/common/from_params.py:394, in construct_arg(class_name, argument_name, popped_params, annotation, default, **extras)
    389         raise TypeError(
    390             f"Expected {argument_name} to be a Mapping (probably a dict or a Params object)."
    391         )
    393     for key, value_params in popped_params.items():
--> 394         value_dict[key] = construct_arg(
    395             str(value_cls),
    396             argument_name + "." + key,
    397             value_params,
    398             value_cls,
    399             _NO_DEFAULT,
    400             **extras,
    401         )
    403     return value_dict
    405 elif origin in (Tuple, tuple) and all(can_construct_from_params(arg) for arg in args):

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/common/from_params.py:348, in construct_arg(class_name, argument_name, popped_params, annotation, default, **extras)
    346     elif isinstance(popped_params, dict):
    347         popped_params = Params(popped_params)
--> 348     result = annotation.from_params(params=popped_params, **subextras)
    350     return result
    351 elif not optional:
    352     # Not optional and not supplied, that's an error!

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/common/from_params.py:604, in FromParams.from_params(cls, params, constructor_to_call, constructor_to_inspect, **extras)
    602     # mypy can't follow the typing redirection that we do, so we explicitly cast here.
    603     retyped_subclass = cast(Type[T], subclass)
--> 604     return retyped_subclass.from_params(
    605         params=params,
    606         constructor_to_call=constructor_to_call,
    607         constructor_to_inspect=constructor_to_inspect,
    608         **extras,
    609     )
    610 else:
    611     # In some rare cases, we get a registered subclass that does _not_ have a
    612     # from_params method (this happens with Activations, for instance, where we
   (...)
    615     # you've done the right thing in passing your parameters, and nothing else needs to
    616     # be recursively constructed.
    617     return subclass(**params)  # type: ignore

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/common/from_params.py:638, in FromParams.from_params(cls, params, constructor_to_call, constructor_to_inspect, **extras)
    635     constructor_to_inspect = cast(Callable[..., T], constructor_to_inspect)
    636     kwargs = create_kwargs(constructor_to_inspect, cls, params, **extras)
--> 638 return constructor_to_call(**kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/data/token_indexers/pretrained_transformer_mismatched_indexer.py:58, in PretrainedTransformerMismatchedIndexer.__init__(self, model_name, namespace, max_length, tokenizer_kwargs, **kwargs)
     56 super().__init__(**kwargs)
     57 # The matched version v.s. mismatched
---> 58 self._matched_indexer = PretrainedTransformerIndexer(
     59     model_name,
     60     namespace=namespace,
     61     max_length=max_length,
     62     tokenizer_kwargs=tokenizer_kwargs,
     63     **kwargs,
     64 )
     65 self._allennlp_tokenizer = self._matched_indexer._allennlp_tokenizer
     66 self._tokenizer = self._matched_indexer._tokenizer

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/data/token_indexers/pretrained_transformer_indexer.py:56, in PretrainedTransformerIndexer.__init__(self, model_name, namespace, max_length, tokenizer_kwargs, **kwargs)
     54 super().__init__(**kwargs)
     55 self._namespace = namespace
---> 56 self._allennlp_tokenizer = PretrainedTransformerTokenizer(
     57     model_name, tokenizer_kwargs=tokenizer_kwargs
     58 )
     59 self._tokenizer = self._allennlp_tokenizer.tokenizer
     60 self._added_to_vocabulary = False

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/data/tokenizers/pretrained_transformer_tokenizer.py:72, in PretrainedTransformerTokenizer.__init__(self, model_name, add_special_tokens, max_length, tokenizer_kwargs, verification_tokens)
     68 self._model_name = model_name
     70 from allennlp.common import cached_transformers
---> 72 self.tokenizer = cached_transformers.get_tokenizer(
     73     self._model_name, add_special_tokens=False, **self._tokenizer_kwargs
     74 )
     76 self._add_special_tokens = add_special_tokens
     77 self._max_length = max_length

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allennlp/common/cached_transformers.py:204, in get_tokenizer(model_name, **kwargs)
    202 tokenizer = _tokenizer_cache.get(cache_key, None)
    203 if tokenizer is None:
--> 204     tokenizer = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
    205         model_name,
    206         **kwargs,
    207     )
    208     _tokenizer_cache[cache_key] = tokenizer
    209 return tokenizer

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/tokenization_auto.py:535, in AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *inputs, **kwargs)
    533 if config_tokenizer_class is None:
    534     if not isinstance(config, PretrainedConfig):
--> 535         config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(
    536             pretrained_model_name_or_path, trust_remote_code=trust_remote_code, **kwargs
    537         )
    538     config_tokenizer_class = config.tokenizer_class
    539     if hasattr(config, "auto_map") and "AutoTokenizer" in config.auto_map:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/configuration_auto.py:705, in AutoConfig.from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    703 kwargs["name_or_path"] = pretrained_model_name_or_path
    704 trust_remote_code = kwargs.pop("trust_remote_code", False)
--> 705 config_dict, _ = PretrainedConfig.get_config_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    706 if "auto_map" in config_dict and "AutoConfig" in config_dict["auto_map"]:
    707     if not trust_remote_code:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py:553, in PretrainedConfig.get_config_dict(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    551 original_kwargs = copy.deepcopy(kwargs)
    552 # Get config dict associated with the base config file
--> 553 config_dict, kwargs = cls._get_config_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    555 # That config file may point us toward another config file to use.
    556 if "configuration_files" in config_dict:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py:601, in PretrainedConfig._get_config_dict(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    595         config_file = hf_bucket_url(
    596             pretrained_model_name_or_path, filename=configuration_file, revision=revision, mirror=None
    597         )
    599 try:
    600     # Load from URL or cache if already cached
--> 601     resolved_config_file = cached_path(
    602         config_file,
    603         cache_dir=cache_dir,
    604         force_download=force_download,
    605         proxies=proxies,
    606         resume_download=resume_download,
    607         local_files_only=local_files_only,
    608         use_auth_token=use_auth_token,
    609         user_agent=user_agent,
    610     )
    612 except RepositoryNotFoundError:
    613     raise EnvironmentError(
    614         f"{pretrained_model_name_or_path} is not a local folder and is not a valid model identifier listed on "
    615         "'https://huggingface.co/models'\nIf this is a private repository, make sure to pass a token having "
    616         "permission to this repo with `use_auth_token` or log in with `huggingface-cli login` and pass "
    617         "`use_auth_token=True`."
    618     )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/utils/hub.py:284, in cached_path(url_or_filename, cache_dir, force_download, proxies, resume_download, user_agent, extract_compressed_file, force_extract, use_auth_token, local_files_only)
    280     local_files_only = True
    282 if is_remote_url(url_or_filename):
    283     # URL, so get it from the cache (downloading if necessary)
--> 284     output_path = get_from_cache(
    285         url_or_filename,
    286         cache_dir=cache_dir,
    287         force_download=force_download,
    288         proxies=proxies,
    289         resume_download=resume_download,
    290         user_agent=user_agent,
    291         use_auth_token=use_auth_token,
    292         local_files_only=local_files_only,
    293     )
    294 elif os.path.exists(url_or_filename):
    295     # File, and it exists.
    296     output_path = url_or_filename

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/utils/hub.py:594, in get_from_cache(url, cache_dir, force_download, proxies, etag_timeout, resume_download, user_agent, use_auth_token, local_files_only)
    591 with temp_file_manager() as temp_file:
    592     logger.info(f"{url} not found in cache or force_download set to True, downloading to {temp_file.name}")
--> 594     http_get(url_to_download, temp_file, proxies=proxies, resume_size=resume_size, headers=headers)
    596 logger.info(f"storing {url} in cache at {cache_path}")
    597 os.replace(temp_file.name, cache_path)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/utils/hub.py:438, in http_get(url, temp_file, proxies, resume_size, headers)
    435 total = resume_size + int(content_length) if content_length is not None else None
    436 # `tqdm` behavior is determined by `utils.logging.is_progress_bar_enabled()`
    437 # and can be set using `utils.logging.enable/disable_progress_bar()`
--> 438 progress = tqdm(
    439     unit="B",
    440     unit_scale=True,
    441     unit_divisor=1024,
    442     total=total,
    443     initial=resume_size,
    444     desc="Downloading",
    445 )
    446 for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
    447     if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/utils/logging.py:312, in _tqdm_cls.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    310 def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    311     if _tqdm_active:
--> 312         return tqdm_lib.tqdm(*args, **kwargs)
    313     else:
    314         return EmptyTqdm(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/notebook.py:242, in tqdm_notebook.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    240 unit_scale = 1 if self.unit_scale is True else self.unit_scale or 1
    241 total = self.total * unit_scale if self.total else self.total
--> 242 self.container = self.status_printer(self.fp, total, self.desc, self.ncols)
    243 self.container.pbar = proxy(self)
    244 self.displayed = False

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/notebook.py:120, in tqdm_notebook.status_printer(_, total, desc, ncols)
    118     raise ImportError(WARN_NOIPYW)
    119 if total:
--> 120     pbar = IProgress(min=0, max=total)
    121 else:  # No total? Show info style bar with no progress tqdm status
    122     pbar = IProgress(min=0, max=1)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipywidgets/widgets/widget_float.py:26, in _Float.__init__(self, value, **kwargs)
     24 if value is not None:
     25     kwargs['value'] = value
---> 26 super().__init__(**kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipywidgets/widgets/widget_description.py:35, in DescriptionWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     33     kwargs.setdefault('tooltip', kwargs['description_tooltip'])
     34     del kwargs['description_tooltip']
---> 35 super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipywidgets/widgets/widget.py:504, in Widget.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    501 super().__init__(**kwargs)
    503 Widget._call_widget_constructed(self)
--> 504 self.open()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipywidgets/widgets/widget.py:517, in Widget.open(self)
    515 """Open a comm to the frontend if one isn't already open."""
    516 if self.comm is None:
--> 517     state, buffer_paths, buffers = _remove_buffers(self.get_state())
    519     args = dict(target_name='jupyter.widget',
    520                 data={'state': state, 'buffer_paths': buffer_paths},
    521                 buffers=buffers,
    522                 metadata={'version': __protocol_version__}
    523                 )
    524     if self._model_id is not None:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipywidgets/widgets/widget.py:615, in Widget.get_state(self, key, drop_defaults)
    613 for k in keys:
    614     to_json = self.trait_metadata(k, 'to_json', self._trait_to_json)
--> 615     value = to_json(getattr(self, k), self)
    616     if not drop_defaults or not self._compare(value, traits[k].default_value):
    617         state[k] = value

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:700, in TraitType.__get__(self, obj, cls)
    698     return self
    699 else:
--> 700     return self.get(obj, cls)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:656, in TraitType.get(self, obj, cls)
    653     value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
    654 except KeyError:
    655     # Check for a dynamic initializer.
--> 656     default = obj.trait_defaults(self.name)
    657     if default is Undefined:
    658         warn(
    659             "Explicit using of Undefined as the default value "
    660             "is deprecated in traitlets 5.0, and may cause "
   (...)
    663             stacklevel=2,
    664         )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:1868, in HasTraits.trait_defaults(self, *names, **metadata)
   1865         raise TraitError(f"'{n}' is not a trait of '{type(self).__name__}' instances")
   1867 if len(names) == 1 and len(metadata) == 0:
-> 1868     return self._get_trait_default_generator(names[0])(self)
   1870 trait_names = self.trait_names(**metadata)
   1871 trait_names.extend(names)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:624, in TraitType.default(self, obj)
    622     return self.default_value
    623 elif hasattr(self, "make_dynamic_default"):
--> 624     return self.make_dynamic_default()
    625 else:
    626     # Undefined will raise in TraitType.get
    627     return self.default_value

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipywidgets/widgets/trait_types.py:365, in InstanceDict.make_dynamic_default(self)
    364 def make_dynamic_default(self):
--> 365     return self.klass(*(self.default_args or ()),
    366                       **(self.default_kwargs or {}))

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipywidgets/widgets/widget_layout.py:86, in Layout.__init__(self, **kwargs)
     83     for side in ['top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left']:
     84         kwargs.setdefault(f'border_{side}', border)
---> 86 super().__init__(**kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipywidgets/widgets/widget.py:504, in Widget.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    501 super().__init__(**kwargs)
    503 Widget._call_widget_constructed(self)
--> 504 self.open()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipywidgets/widgets/widget.py:535, in Widget.open(self)
    531         from ipykernel.comm import Comm
    533         return Comm(**kwargs)
--> 535 self.comm = create_comm(**args)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/corr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/comm/__init__.py:27, in _create_comm(*args, **kwargs)
     22 def _create_comm(*args, **kwargs):
     23     """Create a Comm.
     24 
     25     This method is intended to be replaced, so that it returns your Comm instance.
     26     """
---> 27     raise NotImplementedError("Cannot ")

NotImplementedError: Cannot
```

I need to use this library, and I can't fix it. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Creating fresh python (3.10.12) environment from the scratch with the following dependencies have solved my problem. Here are the dependencies:

```
pip install spacy~=3.3.0
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
pip install neuralcoref --no-binary neuralcoref
pip install allennlp
pip install allennlp-models
```